# Adding records from a fresh table to datagridview in vb.net using msaccess

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

The scenario I am facing is : I am new to vb.net

I have a form for Vendors, where I am simply putting in the vendor info, and below I want to add products for that respective vendors.

the approach I am using is - I have created a temp table in Access, Tmp_Products which is a replica of the original. I have this as the datasource for the datagridview. but the problem is since it's a fresh new table and there's no records so how can I add rows because when I run the form it only shows the columns from the tmp_prodcuts table.

Once I have the tmp_products updated then I will be moving values from this to the original products table and will make it empty again .

Is there any other approach too.

Thanks In Advance

Omer

Comment: perhaps if you told us what you were trying to do rather than HOW, we could offer an alternative.  Unless you are changing the schema, there is usually little reason to move data to/from temp tables.  In fact, there are many reasons not to.

Comment: I have a vendors form where all master info is saved. Below I am using a datagridview where users can enter product for the new vendor (whose master info is just saved). So the data grid is bound to a temporary table in access, and once the information has been entered in the grid let's say 4 products then I will use this info from the temp table and will move to the actual Products table.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a temp table either.  I would look at creating a query to get only the records you want to show